# ClickOnce cant see files, copied during PostBuild event

Tags: .net, deployment, msbuild, directory, clickonce

Nuget package added postbuild event:

```
if not exist "$(TargetDir)x86" md "$(TargetDir)x86"
xcopy /s /y "$(SolutionDir)packages\SqlServerCompact.4.0.8482.1\NativeBinaries\x86\*.*" "$(TargetDir)x86"
if not exist "$(TargetDir)amd64" md "$(TargetDir)amd64"
xcopy /s /y "$(SolutionDir)packages\SqlServerCompact.4.0.8482.1\NativeBinaries\amd64\*.*" "$(TargetDir)amd64"
```

and it works when i just compile.
 When i want to publish - these directories(x86, amd64) do not appear in Application Files.  I dont want to copy existing files, because nuget package will be updated and existing copies will change, so that i will have to remember that i need to re-add them. How to deploy these exact directories(embedded sqlce needs exactly such structure) with files via clickonce and make that process not dependent on package version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found answer here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2514027/47672
In my case the code was:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="$(TargetDir)x86\*.dll">
      <Link>x86\%(FileName)%(Extension)</Link>
      <Visible>false</Visible>
    </Content>
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="$(TargetDir)x86\Microsoft.VC90.CRT\*.dll">
      <Link>x86\Microsoft.VC90.CRT\%(FileName)%(Extension)</Link>
      <Visible>false</Visible>
    </Content>
</ItemGroup>
```